# Make a nested object in C++

Tags: c++, object

I come from javascript and am trying to understand objects in C++
I am trying to make a C++ object like this:

```
var myObject = {
    first: {
        first: {
            first:"11first",second:"11second"
        },
        second: {
            first:"12first",second:"12second"
        }
    },
    second: {
        first: {
            first:"21first",second:"21second"
        },
        second: {
            first:"22first",second:"22second"
        }
    }
}
```

The only way I found of making objects in C++ was with classes. I also want to add items to the object with code. Is there a way to make a C++ object behave like this?

Comment: If you want something that looks/acts/feels a lot like a JavaScript object in C++, you'll probably want to use some JSON library to do it. Unless you have some fairly specific reason to use a different one, I generally recommend [Nlohmann's JSON library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json). That said, C++ is not JavaScript. If you want to write JavaScript, you're probably best off sticking with JavaScript. If you're going to write C++, you're probably better off learning to write C++ and using it as C++. Trying to write JavaScript in C++ is unlikely to work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create nested objects on C++ like Javascript, but in order to understand how it works, you need to learn about types and functions mainly, you could visit [learncpp.com](https://learncpp.com) to read about how C++ works.

Now, answering your question the syntax to create a class on C++ is the following:

```
class "ClassName:{

    Access specifier:
    "Attributes"

    "Constructors"

    "Member functions"

}
```

In order to create a class you need to use the **class** keyword followed by the class name and curly braces. Inside the curly braces, you will put all the attibutes your class has (first and second on your JSON), but C++ is static typed, so it means you need to specify what type your attribute is (integer, char, or another class).

The access specifier (public, protected or private) just says if you can access those attributes outside your class to be used like **className.attributeName**.

The constructors are used to initialize the attributes of your class while member functions like getters/setters for instance, are used to retrieve or change the data of the attributes of your class, of course you can create functions in order to manipulate the data in other aways (add/delete objects, memory allocation, arrays/list and other containers, etc).

As a brief example:

```
class Animal {

public:     //Access specifier

    std::string name;       //Public attribute

    /*
        No need of contructor or functions since name attribute can be accesed outside the class
    */
};

class Person {

private:        //Access specifier

    std::string name;       //Private attribute of type string
    int age;        //Private attribute of type int
    Animal pet;     //Private attribute of type Animal (class)


public:

    /*
        class constructor need to has the same name of the class "Person"

        this constructor takes 3 parameters and initialize the attribute values with those parameters.
    */

    Person(std::string name, int age, Animal pet) : name{ name }, age{ age }, pet{ pet } {
        
    }

    /*
        setter
    */

    void setName(const std::string &name) {
        this->name = name;
    }

    /*
        getter
    */

    const std::string& getName() const {
        return name;
    }

};

int main() {

    Animal dog;
    dog.name = "Fluffy";        //allowed cause name attribute on class Animal if public

    Person p = Person("nick", 25, dog);     //constructor call
    p.setName("mike");      //now person name changed from nick to mike

    p.name = "alex";        //Not allowed, name attribute on class Person is private

}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, C++ using the static typing of objects, so you can't change the object after you created its class definition.
You can use inheritance and templates to achieve some similar results, but not as easy as it is in Javascript.

Comment: What are inheritance and templates?

Comment: @FourCinnamon0 I recommend reading/browsing through these tutorial and explanations of Object-Oriented Programming (OOP) in C++ and look at their examples.
[GeeksforGeeks C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-oriented-programming-in-cpp/) and [W3Schools C++](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_oop.asp)